# How to use css value for javascript in IF-THEN construction?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to rotate through three div's changing every 10 seconds.  I found a few examples of jquery options, but I want to do this with pure javascript.  Code below looks like it should work, but it does not.

```
 function changediv() {
    If(document.getElementById('co5').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('co3').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('co4').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('co5').style.display = 'none';
    }
    elseif(document.getElementById('co3').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('co3').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('co4').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('co5').style.display = 'none';
    }
    elseif(document.getElementById('co4').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('co3').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('co4').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('co5').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
setInterval(changediv, 10000);
```

Comment: Looks more like a mess to me? Uppercase `I` on the first `If ` is a syntax error, and it just keeps on ...

Comment: Clean up your code a bit by saving off the dom elements as variables and that might help a bit in readability (i.e. `var co5 = document.getElementById('co5');`).

Comment: Well. Now you edited all your mistakes I mentioned in my post. What is your problem now?

Comment: I didn't edit my mistakes, not sure how that happened.

Comment: I did make the changes recommended and it still is not working, I'm going to try converting the dom elements to variables now and I'll report back.

Comment: Ahaha oh my god :D I edited your post. I thought its mine. Sorry D: I have to sleep sometimes! :D

Comment: @Rhys8582 you accepted my answer. Was it full or should I clarify something? Ask in comments to the answer, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You using `elseif`, but you have to use `else if`. [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Use this:

```
function changediv(){
    if (document.getElementById('co5').style.display == 'block') {
       document.getElementById('co3').style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById('co4').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('co5').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (document.getElementById('co3').style.display == 'block') {
       document.getElementById('co3').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('co4').style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById('co5').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (document.getElementById('co4').style.display == 'block') {
       document.getElementById('co3').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('co4').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('co5').style.display = 'block';
    }   
}

setInterval(changediv, 10000);
```

Also, as [@adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) mentioned in comments to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528818/how-to-use-css-value-for-javascript-if-then):

> Looks more like a mess to me? Uppercase `I` on the first `If` is a
>   syntax error, and it just keeps on ...

Use `if`, instead of `If`.

Comment: This works, although it is still not working ideally.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong but the setInterval doesn't load at the start up.  I have to mouse over a menu item or something that initiates another javascript command, and then it starts working.  Gonna have to look into that one another day.

Comment: Try to put this code into `document.ondomcontentready` or `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

try this, usin switch http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var i = 0;
        function change()
        {
            i++;
            switch(i)
            {
                case 1:
                    document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("d2").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("d3").style.display = "none";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("d2").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("d3").style.display = "none";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("d2").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("d3").style.display = "block";
                    break;
            }
            if(i==3){i=0}
        }
        setInterval(change, 1000);
    </script>

    <div id="d1">1</div>
    <div id="d2">2</div>
    <div id="d3">3</div>

    <style>
        div{display:none; width:50px; text-align:center; font-size:25px; border: solid 2px rgb(100,100,100); border-radius:10px; color: white;}
        #d1{background: red}
        #d2{background: green}
        #d3{background: blue}
    </style>

</body>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, and in fact it is what I started with and it worked fine.  However, there is also an external way to change the "focus" to any one of the three divs, the idea is that when the "focus" is off of the divs, the function will continue from that point and not start over.  Hence why I want it to be based on the current display state.